# Is this possible to hi-hack React render method to assign a customized prefix for the key?

Tags: reactjs

I got a react component that has a render method, which will generate a list of components. Inside the render method, which generated components assign a key, and that's work great!

But the issue is, when I display two component on the same page, it will have a duplicated error. It was because the render method assigns the same key value.

Without modified the code inside the component's method is this possible to assign a `prefix` in the component generated key? Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK key should be unique in one level. so rendering two component should not result the key duplication.

Comment: If this component returns an array then two sibling components will have two arrays on the same level. If this is the case then wrapping components in a `div` or something like that should help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the index as keys for rendering. Please do not use it. Instead if you have access to lodash, use uniqueId() method which does the work for you. Need not worry about duplicate keys anymore.